# Approval And Rejection For Multiuser

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle11g

We Have a table of approval like below:

[image: Sql table]

In above table we have `ApprovalId` and `ApprovalLevel` like first level approval and second level approval in `ApprovalLevel` (For Approving Approval by its level).
I am trying to fetch record in query if specific user `ApprovalLevel >= 1` then check its previous `ApprovalStatus` if it Approved then show its record too.

I have tried many things but still not getting specify record.

In Simple term select record with User if only if its `ApprovalLevel=1` or its previous `ApprovalLevel` `ApprovalStatus=1`.

Please help me on this: `[IN this table ApprovalStatus: 0 = Pending and 1:Approved]`

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: have tryied Qry: SELECT ApprovalStatus,ApprovalLevel,CreatedOn FROM approval 
WHERE ApprovalStatus=0 AND UserId=1 and ApprovalLevel=1 and(Here cundution for selecting previous Approvel level whose status is 1) 
:(

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are requesting:

```
SELECT
    ApprovalStatus,
    ApprovalLevel,
    CreatedOn
FROM
    approval
WHERE
    ApprovalLevel = 1
    OR (ApprovalLevel > 1 AND ApprovalStatus = 1)
;
```

Comment: I want to select Approval Level > 1 only if its previous level ApprovalStatus is 1(means if APprovalLevel 1 will approval it then it goes to Approval Level 2)